# Requests gives 404 instead of 200

Tags: python, networking, python-requests

I am trying to make an URL fuzzer in python 3 using requests
I made a demo but is not working properly (I get 404 responses instead of 200)

```
#install requests
import requests as rq

with open('fuzz.txt','r') as file:
        words = file.readlines()


url = "https://www.somewebsite.com"
for i in words :
    print(url + i)
    urll = rq.get(url + i)
    resp = urll.status_code
    print(resp)
```

in the .txt file I have some random words like : /admin.html , /login.html ....
I've made a website which contains a few of the words mentioned ,in the url , but instead of getting 200 as resp I get 404 (the page exist , is hosted on github)

Comment: HTTP's 400 error codes always client side errors. make sure your URL is legit and check your params you are passing into the requests.get() method.

Comment: `for i in words` When you loop through the lines of a file this way, the lines will have a newline `\n` at the end.  So you're requesting a url that ends in a newline, i.e. `http://website.com/login.html\n`.  Perhaps this is the issue.

Comment: Try replacing `words = file.readlines()` with `words = file.read().splitlines()`.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm wondering if there might be an invisible \n or such at the end of your i variable that's causing that. Try to print(urll.url) and print(url.text) to see what you're getting. Also, urll.request might show what's being sent that is wrong.

Comment: I tried that autonopy, i think not that is the problem

Comment: @FishingCode that's wrong.  A variable created inside a `with` block will persist outside of the block.

Comment: Wait i am an idiot again , my apologies , @PApostol was

Comment: Thanks all for your time <3

Answer (score -1):

Remember to add slashes in between each particular part of the URL link that you create each time going through the loop, as well as the status_code method is `urll.status_code()`.Make sure to add parenthesis to indicate its a particular method in the request module.

Comment: Thx , now i have this error. TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in line 10

Comment: `response.status_code` is a plain attribute; it is NOT a function.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp , you are right